# Hero ViewController animation with collectionView - swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller whenever I tap on a `collection view cell`with the `zoom` effect.

As far as I know Hero framework works using `HeroID`'s, you set the same id in the `fromView` and in the `toView` and the frameworks does the hard work for you.

I have set It up this way:

in `viewcontroller1` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.heroID = "profheroid"
    let viewcontroller2 = ViewController2()
    viewcontroller2.configureController(with: arrayOfModels[indexPath.item])
    viewcontroller2.heroModalAnimationType = .zoom
    viewcontroller2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.present(viewcontroller2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and in `viewcontroller2`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.heroID = "profheroid"
}
```

The problem happens whenever I tap on a `collectionviewCell` the presentation happens correctly but I see so many cells being presented at the same time.
I think this happens because `cell.heroID = "profheroid"` is applied to more cells at the same time.

How can I make sure that when the cell is presented the heroID's are only in the `cell` tapped and in the viewcontroller's view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must clear this heroID when cell is reused and after VC is presented.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    cell.heroID = nil // or empty
}
```

Comment: Clear, but how can I have the reference of the cell in the vc2 in order to clear it after the vc2 is presented?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must reset heroID to nil in cellForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: YourCollectionViewCell.description(), for: indexPath) as? YourCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    cell.heroID = nil
    
    return cell
}
```

Reset all visible cell's heroID to nil, and only set heroID for cell selected with value before present:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        cell.heroID = nil //reset heroID
    }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }

    cell.heroID = "profheroid"
    let viewcontroller2 = ViewController2()
    viewcontroller2.configureController(with: arrayOfModels[indexPath.item])
    viewcontroller2.heroModalAnimationType = .zoom
    viewcontroller2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.present(viewcontroller2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```